# Word for synonyms with different degree

Tags: terminology, synonymy, lexical-relations

How call words expressing same thing but varying degree?
`hot - warm - cold - frozen`

Comment: These express qualities, *painful*, *solid*, so they are not nearly synonymous, but they also express *quantities*. This is a paradigm, I believe, for which the prototypical example is the personal pronouns, and the irregular paradigm in *to be*. A paradigm is also an idiom (as far as the order of the pronouns is an arbitrarily fixed mnemonic, "I, you, he, she, it"). I am not sure whether that's the answer you are looking fo, so I'll leave it for someone else to bring up highly specialized terminology.

Comment: "gradual" -----

Comment: "Degree" can refer to any variation -- like high-mid-low or -2 to +4. Not everything lies on a countable scale. There are clines like _boiling-hot-warm-tepid-cool-cold-freezing_ which have distinct poles and preset stops; but most adjectives aren't like that. Colors need more than one dimension, and use real numbers; emotions aren't that descriptive, because after any polar term like _furious_, everything is metaphoric and isn't ordered by degree. Nouns use quantifiers, but there's only so many of them, too. No special term for any of this, afaik.

Comment: @jlawler arent red and green synonymous in sense of color but express varying degrees of wavelenght of light reflected?

Comment: @vectory i dont believe synonymous words in every sense exist, unless each in different language and not even

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy and esp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy#/media/File:Hyponym_and_hypernym.svg

Comment: In my undergrad days, we used to refer to this as "semantic fields" - see e.g. Cruse, D. A. (1986). Lexical semantics. Cambridge, U.K.: Cambridge University Press.

Comment: @AlexB.: yes, that rings a bell. And _field_ has both 2-dimensional metaphoric and  N-dimensional mathematical definitions that fit into the semantics. Not  to mention force fields like F = ma. But you have to be **very** careful with definitions and specifications. Consult Wordnet or Framenet, for instance.

Comment: @AlexB. thanks! very helpful will accept it as answer if you care

Comment: I might call it a *spectrum* of *gradable antonyms*.